# How to install MySQL server on Mac (OS X 10.6.8) from command line?

Tags: mysql, installation

How to install MySQL server on Mac (OS X 10.6.8) from command line?  If I donwload the .dmg file, is it possible to install it from command line?

Answer (score 1):

If you have homebrew installed, then :

```
brew install mysql
```

Else install homebrew it might be useful also to install other projects

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going by the way of [ports](http://www.macports.org/):

```
sudo port install mysql5
sudo port activate mysql5
```

Even simpler is the [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) way, but the MAMP distribution is usually behind the macport one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't need the latest version 5.1. I downloaded tar.gz file for 5.0 and would like to install that.

Comment: Did you follow [Installing MySQL on Mac OS X](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/macosx-installation.html)?